# How to manage repetitive no-work or no progress with some of your teammates or employee?

Tags: management, ethics, software-development, team, leadership

Here are a couple of things about myself:

- I'm a co-founder and joined the start-up after 1 year.
- I have real SWE, Architecture and management experience in many other start-ups in Silicon Valley.
- I manage a team of 5 engineers and discuss with 4 other co-founders + one founder.
- My management style is very driven, involving learning, result-oriented and sharing a vision.
- Most of my team are paid. I don't pay myself but definitely put in a lot of time and sweat.

Recently, after nearly 2 years, I'm starting to see clear misalignment and inexperience in the c-level team and creating culture problems for no reason.

We had numerous situations where some employees were not delivering any work for months prior to when I joined. We had to fire one person because he refused to work with the team (e.g. blocking others from advancing...) and "under" or what I prefer to say with me- I never understood why and even tried to talk things out. He was adamant.

I'm running now in a similar situation after 1 year without too many issues and we had a good delivery pace, good team, good discussion, etc. For 2 months, I have had one of my engineers that didn't deliver a single thing and busted the deadline more than 3 times. Every time he was late I was very empathetic and tried to understand the situation, and always proposed my help. He always refused and reiterate that it should be good next time. I also just ping him once a week or so to check his status, and again always let him know that I'm here.

Well, a week ago he snapped at me or behind my back, and it was not pretty. He's also bad-mouthing me to the founder. I was completely in shock and in awe - to be honest, I never experienced those kinds of situations before.

I have to say that I did not choose my team so it was a hard adjustment to slow down to their pace. I used to be working with very good engineers - short way to say that it just impacted our velocity, and personality wise as also some impact on the culture.

The c-level was expecting his deliverables and at some point, I had to share with them that we had a problem, and I was unable to get a sense from him of what was going on, or where he was in terms of progress. I have to say that I implemented some workflows and obviously if you are an engineer, you have to work with a version control system, GitHub for example. Well, he never pushes code and it's always very cryptic...

For me, it's completely nuts and unacceptable. All other of his teammates are pushing their code and we can clearly see progress - that match their communication.

So in short, I was very disappointed and yes, frustrated because of the way he talked about me and also the fact he didn't talk to me directly or never reached out for help. He's also lying blatantly about his progress and our communication with the founder - FYI every thing is written and I can see some of his code timestamps on some other tools we use (no work for 2 months). I'm left with three options:

- Don't trust him, and change my approach to dealing with his deliverables.
- Take for granted that he did not do any work and start ASAP what he was supposed to deliver.
- Step back a bit and let him to his own demise... again.

The founder also told me that I come from "elitist start-ups". I was again a bit in shock and just ignored, but said in terms of experience maybe if you say so, but replied to him that if he wanted to pay someone to do nothing without consequence. I would no longer trust nor put to work for that individual.

Other individuals in my team shared their concerns and kept asking me why he doesn't push any code. They are also starting to question his progress during our weekly.

This whole situation is driving me a bit crazy because I keep telling myself: Am I the problem? Do I fit with this culture? Should I just lay low? Is it worth it? Should I just do the work? Should I even leave?

I would greatly appreciate a neutral opinion. In my book, I like to say: "How many strikes before you can hit a home run?"

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your post and *what question you want us to answer*. There's a lot of details in here which make it sound like a general outpouring of frustration. Can you try editing it to more clearly focus on one specific problem and the details that are relevant to that problem.

Comment: It's been years, according to you, what happened during the annual assessment interview? You didn't do any performance review? No goals or expected improvement?

Comment: You already fired 1 person. What makes you hesitate to fire this **second employee** ? Can you tell the manager that he underperforms, and that you can fire him to hire a more productive worker ? -- Does this **second employee** have some special protection or special relationship to the founders, and therefore he can underperform and still keep the job ?

Comment: The problem is that the founder is not taking my warning seriously, and yes, this second employee has a relationship and did deliver in the past I have to give him that (but he still didn't follow our standards and workflows). He's also telling me to chill when I'm a performer sometimes I feel like nothing is serious. The founder is also very very human and basically gives chances like no tomorrow to people around him.
This type of indecisiveness from the founder, giving 3+ chances are driving me nuts and is slowing the team.

Comment: "not paying yourself" and letting someone else make those hard hiring and firing decisions about developers, that's a recipe for disaster. I realize you're heavily invested into this startup, a year of sweat equity without getting paid is a long time, but I think you should at least consider leaving this startup if you're really not allowed to fire such non-performant developers. And I don't actually expect you to listen to me, but I thought that I should at least mention that option to you even if you feel you could never take it.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether or not you have any actual authority over this person. Do you? If you do then it seems like you've gotten past the point of having conversations and making requests - you need to issue firm instructions for what this person needs to do in order to continue working in this role. "Push commits to git not less frequently than xxx (irrespective of amount of code written)", "email status updates briefly describing progress on xyz every week", or whatever works for you. Assuming you have the authority to issue thses instructions, the founder's opinion is secondary.

Comment: I, unfortunately, have no more authority at this point - and the said individual bypasses me to go directly to the founder. Now, it's creating obviously friction between me and the founder. As for the employee, it's a lost cause. We tried to have a 3-way conversation but had no success.

I've decided to prove my point and will do his job in less than 3 days. I gave him nearly 2 months. If the founder still doesn't get my point and work the card of empathy. I'm going to lose it, and just call it quit. Not a culture I want to work with.

Comment: "**I've decided to prove my point and will do his job in less than 3 days**". Can you show your work to him and ask him for his opinion as to what difficulty he faces and can't getting it done in 3 days ? Is it because he does not understand the requirements or does not have enough coding skills ? -- Try to be constructive and helpful with him to see if that resolves the problematic situation ?

Comment: Is this employee a family member, relative, or close friend of the founders ? Does he have a lot personal influence toward the founders ?

Comment: If this employee does not commit his code to GitHub, does he have a way to protect his code in case of unexpected disasters such as his computer crashes and he may lose a few months of work ?

Comment: If you can perform his tasks in 3 days, that you have allowed (days, weeks, or months) to be completed, there is something wrong with the schedule. Seems “you shall” statements should be used.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest red flag I see here is that he missed *three* consecutive deadlines, but did not ask *anybody* for help. You don't know what he does, the team does not know what he does.

Missing a deadline *once* (in a while) is acceptable and maybe they just misjudged their work and they get it done faster without taking an extra day explaining it to someone who can help. But three times? This person is either stuck and needs help, or secretly working for someone else on the side.

Coming from an agile background, having a coordination meeting just once a week is already baffling, but not pushing code while missing dealines is unacceptable. If he decided to quit tomorrow, you would have nothing. *Nothing*.

We have a rule in our team to push once a day at least, so if something happens to your machine, we are not set back more than a day. I think that is perfectly reasonable, just as an IT backup rule, not even development specific.

Let me compare that to construction: You asked someone to build a wall. The wall is not done the first time. Not done the second time. Not done the third time. And the guy is not even wearing a helmet or safety shoes! Just a bum sitting at your construction site starring at stones.

If you have the authority to fire him, you need to sit down with him, explain what is expected and give him one more chance. *Not* to turtle back into his shell and fail again. But to involve his team, share his problems and ask for help. If he cannot do this, he has to go. I am not a big fan of blaming any problems on a single person, the only problem you *can* blame on a single person is that it remained the problem of this single person despite clear evidence that they could not handle it. If they cannot ask for help, they don't belong in a team.

As next step, have a meeting with him and let him lay out exactly what he did so far. What needs to be done until it's "done". Who can do that. Who can help with it.

My best guess is that they did nothing. Because any developer, if they had done something that needed more work, would happily tell you about it. All about it.  For reasons unknown, he does not. I'm pretty sure your meeting will be a big disappointment, because either he has done a little, that you would consider a good mornings work only, or he says "oh, I did a lot, but I had to delete it all, it didn't work out in the end". Yeah. Sure.

Also, gather your team (including him) and discuss and then decide upon some ground rules. For example when to push. Hold everyone to the same standard.

If you cannot fire them, at least ask whoever does not want them fired to move them to another team. If that is not possible, ask those people who are blocking it to come up with a list of things he has to do as a minimum to work at the company in his position. Measure each of your team members against that list and report that back. People are more open to face reality when it is *their own* criteria that get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's certainly an interesting situation.

Before I give my 2c, some questions:

What is the reason he is not pushing code to GIT?

There are some scenarios where I can envision someone being apprehensive about pushing code to GIT - including perfectionist personalities 'I'll only Push once it's done' and people that primarily don't work out of GIT - for example, although primarily a Sysadmin, I dabble in some scripting work in Powershell and SQL and also some BI stuff. I use GIT more as a backup for code that I've completed rather than full version control - because I'm not a programmer, I know I'm not using GIT properly, but at the same time, my Boss knows the progress being made and so trusts me in that regard.

If this is the scenario - where for whatever they aren't committing any Code, I would look at dealing this in 2 ways:

1: Informal training on how to use GIT properly from other team members (this is more so that there can't be any excuses on not knowing how to properly do it)
2: Some form of Company Policy around pushing written code to the a Git repository (even if it's a Dev/Sandbox repo - just to show stuff is being done) at regular intervals - could be daily, or every other day - with the expectation being that if you miss this requirement, an explanation is expected.

The key would be to make sure that the policy isn't draconian so that it annoys the other Team members, but defined enough that if he continues to not perform, you can point to something as a grounds to start a PIP or take action to exit him from the company.

Conversely, it might be he is doing work - but it's not apparent - I had a project where it 'looked' like I was doing nothing for 3 weeks, but the reality was - it wasn't a well defined project and the key people had several last minute 'just slight fixes' that actually required total re-writes...

Next question:

What are the reasons he gives for his apparent lack of output? Are the reasons given just mere excuses or do they tie in with other happenings in the business? Have there been unforseen issues or major pivots on his deliverables that would again make it look like he's doing nothing?

Case in point from me - earlier in the year, we had a relative quiet spot at work, so I decided to reach into the 'things that ought to get done' basket and pulled out my desire to automate some of the various tasks at my job. We do have Puppet, but we are a large entity that has acquired many companies and we are in the process of integrating. So I spent a couple of weeks reading up on possible automation solutions as to what I thought would be best for our needs - and then before I could present any findings, we got told which direction we would be moving in (and it wasn't one of the ones I was going to recommend).

The final thing for me is your line that he's missed 3 deadlines. Unless there's a good reason for doing so (and as above - there can be many good reasons to miss a deadline) I'd say that on the 3rd strike, you are within your rights to suggest putting them on a PIP.

I'd frame the PIP on the *assumption* that they are working hard, but that you want to put in some structure so that you can definitively prove that they are pulling their weight and providing value to the company.

As above, you may want to do the Policy first, wait for them to breach the policy and then go the PIP route - trying to give them the tools to be successful.

Comment: On your first question, no real apparent reason. We are working on an application, and I understand that some more devops/infra/security work is sometimes a little more tricky. So in short, I don't see why he would not push code and improve on it.

Next question, we are a small start-up so there's a lot of uncertainty, and the founder kind of scared everyone that we might run out of money in 2 months and I feel that might trigger something. A lot of us, don't get paid and we work out of sweat equity, and some get a small salary, and he does.